# Firefox drawing some websites off the viewing area

Tags: firefox, display

Some websites which seems to be designed with "responsive" templates are displaying in Firefox with the content off the right side of the viewing area. The issue happens in Firefox Safe Mode and at different browser sizes. Here are two examples, from the [NASA blog](http://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-new-horizons-discovers-frozen-plains-in-the-heart-of-pluto-s-heart) and from [Al Jazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/inpictures/2015/07/running-bulls-150717112246514.html) (Click `View as a List` to test on that page).

Screenshot from Firefox Safe Mode with the browser maximized at the NASA blog:

[image: NASA blog]
***Note the image caption that runs off the right of the screen.***

Screenshot from Firefox Safe Mode with the browser maximized at Al Jazeera:

[image: Al Jazeera]
***Note the photographer name that runs off the right of the screen.***

The Firefox version is 39, as installed by default in Kubuntu 14.10. I do not have the same issue in Chrome 44, i.e. Chrome displays the websites as expected without issue.

Comment: @RogUE: Yes, I mention that Firefox is in Safe Mode for the two screenshots.

Comment: Confirmed in my Firefox on a Mac, which only has Adblock Plus installed, and also when disabled. That's just a bug either in Firefox or in the websites...

Comment: Confirmed in Windows too, firefox 39.